Python CSV Reader & Writer to respect the double quotes
I'm new to Python and working on below use case:
I want my Python script to enhance a csv file.
My input.csv looks like below:
test_case,test_desc,"test data 1","test data 2"
,0,"",

I want to enhance this to add two more columns. So my output.csv should look like below:
test_case,test_desc,"test data 1","test data 2",col_1,col_2
,0,"",,,

I'm using below script:
import csv
from pathlib import Path

source_headers = []
source_data = []

# Read the 'input.csv'
with Path('input.csv').open() as file:
    headers = csv.reader(file)
    for line in headers:
        source_headers = line
        break

with Path('input.csv').open() as file:
    lines = csv.DictReader(file)
    for line in lines:
        source_data.append(line)

print("source_headers: ", source_headers)
print("source_data: ", source_data)

# Specify the target_enhanced_headers
target_enhanced_headers = {'col_1': 'target col_1', 'col_2': 'target col_2'}

enhanced_headers = source_headers
enhanced_headers.extend(target_enhanced_headers)
enhanced_data = source_data

# Enhance the source data
for new_header in target_enhanced_headers:
    enhanced_data[0][new_header] = ''

print("enhanced_headers: ", enhanced_headers)
print("enhanced_data: ", enhanced_data)

# Write new file
with Path('output.csv').open("w", encoding ="utf-8", newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=enhanced_headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(enhanced_data)
    file.close()

The output of this script comes out to be like this:
source_headers:  ['test_case', 'test_desc', 'test data 1', 'test data 2']
source_data:  [{'test_case': '', 'test_desc': '0', 'test data 1': '', 'test data 2': ''}]
enhanced_headers:  ['test_case', 'test_desc', 'test data 1', 'test data 2', 'col_1', 'col_2']
enhanced_data:  [{'test_case': '', 'test_desc': '0', 'test data 1': '', 'test data 2': '', 'col_1': '', 'col_2': ''}]

The output.csv looks like:
test_case,test_desc,test data 1,test data 2,col_1,col_2
    ,0,,,,

It's not respecting the double quotes that are there in the headers and in the data.
How can I make it work in Python by using csv module?

You can see the available quoting options here, for example csv.QUOTE_ALL. It does not offer an option to quote only column names afaik.

Preserving superfluous formatting is kinda hard. If you literally just want to append two columns, you don't even need to parse the entire thing as CSV at all though. Just add ',,' to each line and you're done.

Along with @deceze's comment, all examples of double quotes in your example don't actually quote special values: so the output CSV is semantically equal to the input. It might be that the CSV was generated by a non-CSV aware program (someone tried to manually program a few edge cases). In any case, you should avoid relying on the "appearance" of a CSV. If your program works logically, then go with it: you're producing better CSV than what you started with.

That said, I've seen or heard (here on SO) about many programs/data pipelines that depend on superfluous differences or outright invalid CSV, because... legacy.

@ZachYoung this is precisely why I cringe every time someone adds an answer to a csv question with something like "Here's how to do it without imports!" No! Use the import! Use the standard library!

If you really want the quotes in the header line, you can simply write it as a literal string to the file instead of using DictWriter.writeheader().

As pointed out in the comments, the double quotes in your input aren't necessary, and it's a bit suspect that only one column of the data row has the superfluous quotes.
Python's csv writer is very good at producing valid CSV, if you're okay with whatever it gives you, you can use the DictReader and do one read of everything, maninpulate the header, add columns for every row, then pass the modified header and rows to DictWriter:
import csv

with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = list(reader)  # read the entire CSV into a list of dicts


header = list(data[0].keys())
header += ["col_1", "col_2"]

for row in data:
    row["col_1"] = ""  # "target col_1" ?
    row["col_2"] = ""  # "target col_2" ?


with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)

Running that against the input:
test_case,test_desc,"test data 1","test data 2"
,0,"",

I get this output.csv:
test_case,test_desc,test data 1,test data 2,col_1,col_2
,0,,,,

P.S., are the "target_col" values not actually useful?

target_enhanced_headers = {'col_1': 'target col_1', 'col_2': 'target col_2'}

I don't see them in your example outputs.
